How export a .fit file (non-media) from Apple TV to Mac or Windows via network
I have some .fit files (workout files) on an Apple TV that I would like to copy.  How can I export them to either a Mac Mini or Windows computer on the same network?  I've loaded Filebrowser TV but it doesn't appear to show anything but media files and .pdf's.
